# Django prepopulate non-model formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I've got the following formset in my "add" view. Users can dynamically add forms and adding/saving them works perfectly. Now the problem is that I can't figure out a good way to prepopulate this formset for editing. Under edit users should be able to add and remove forms from the formset.

### View

```
ClassificationFormset = formset_factory(ClassificationForm)
classification_formset = ClassificationFormset(prefix='habitat_fs')
```

### Custom Form

```
class ClassificationForm(forms.Form):

classification = ClassificationField(
    label=_('Habitat Classification'),
    required=False,
    queryset=Classification.objects.all(),
)

community = CommunityField(
    label=_('Community'),
    required=False,
    queryset=Community.objects.none(),
)

def save(self, habitat_id, *args, **kwargs):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    if data:
        habitat_community = Habitat_Community()
        habitat_community.habitat = habitat_id
        habitat_community.community = data['community']
        habitat_community.save()
```

So far I've tried to override **init** and populate fields there...

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    habitat = kwargs.pop('habitat', None)
    super(ClassificationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Populate fields here based on habitat
```

...but formset_factory doesn't allow me to pass in any parameters to my form.

```
ClassificationFormset = formset_factory(ClassificationForm(habitat=habitat_id))
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#s-using-initial-data-with-a-formset It might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set initial for each form like a normal form.

```
def some_method(request):
    ClassificationFormset = formset_factory(ClassificationForm)
    classification_formset = ClassificationFormset(prefix='habitat_fs')
    for form in classification_formset:
        form.initial = {"habitat": "some value"}
```

Edited for clarity.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but I'll accept it as an answer because I couldn't think of a better solution.